# How to store count values in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to compare two tables based on their total number of rows. So i use count(*) to count the total number of rows in both table.

My code is:

```
cur1.execute ("""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;""")
```

In order to store the total count return by this query,

I use

```
row = cur1.fetchone()

 result1 =  row[0]
```

but it didn't help.  Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by *it didn't help*? Did it give you an error? Was the result incorrect or unexpected?

Comment: sorry  it was typo to use cur1 instead of cur..

Comment: @Blair: Yeah I got an error, TypeError: 'long' object is unsubscriptable if i use fetchone.

Comment: @Blair: But it worked while fetchmany was used.

Comment: Here's what you do.  (1) print the results of the fetchone.  Print `row`.  (2) **update** the question with the results.  Don't comment on your own question.  Update your question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.fetchone()
```

gives you the result directly..so no need to take its zeroeth element..what you want is given to you directly when you say:

```
row = cur1.fetchone()
```

Comment: According to Python DB-API standard, fetchone() _should_ return either a sequence or a None.