# Return a mapped dictionary based on multiple queries

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, psycopg2

Issue: I can't figure out how to run a query in the correct way so that it returns a mapped dictionary. The query will use counts from multiple tables.

I am using psycopg2 for a postgresql database, and I will be using the results to create a report on day to day deltas on these counts.

Given that, can someone provide an example on how to execute multiple queries and return a dictionary that I can use for comparison purposes? Thanks! I image in a for loop is needed somewhere in here.

```
tables = ['table1', 'table2']
def db_query():
    query = "select count(*) from (a_table) where error_string != '';"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db, user=user, password=password, host=host)
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur.execute(query, tables)
    output = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used postgresql, so you might want to also check this out as a reference: [How to store count values in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675506/how-to-store-count-values-in-python).

That being said, rearrange your code into something like this. Be sure to make `conn` global so you don't have to make more than one connection, and make sure you're also closing `cur`:

```
conn = None    

def driverFunc():
    global conn
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db, user=user, password=password, host=host)
        tables = ['table1', 'table2']
        countDict = {}
        for thisTable in tables:
            db_query(thisTable, countDict)
    finally:
        if not conn == None:
            conn.close()

def db_query(tableName, countDict):
    # Beware of SQL injection with the following line:
    query = "select count(*) from " + tableName + " where error_string != '';"
    cur = None

    try:
        cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
        cur.execute(query)
        countDict[tableName] = int(cur.fetchone())
    finally:
        if not cur == None:
            cur.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One note, the psycopg2 module documentation strongly advises against string concatenation when running a query. [Psycopg2 Documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html)

Comment: I guess you acknowledged this with the comment.

Comment: This ended up being super helpful, I wasn't quite to figure out the 'proper' way to replace the string concatenation in the query, but since it won't be public this should suffice. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! For your own piece of mind, I'd switch to a parameterized query if possible. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql

Comment: the int(cur.fetchone()) part isn't functioning for me. It registers this error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'DictRow'. Any thoughts?

Comment: How about `int(cur.fetchone()[0])`?